# how to remove rows in python data frame with condition?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have the following data:
df =

```
   Emp_Name   Leaves   Leave_Type   Salary   Performance
0  Christy      20      sick        3000.0    56.6
1  Rocky        10      Casual      kkkk      22.4
2  jenifer      50      Emergency   2500.6   '51.6'
3  Tom          10      sick        Nan       46.2
4  Harry        nn      Casual      1800.1   '58.3'
5  Julie        22      sick        3600.2   'unknown'
6  Sam          5       Casual      Nan       47.2
7  Mady         6       sick        unknown   Nan
```

Output:

```
   Emp_Name   Leaves   Leave_Type   Salary   Performance
0  Christy      20      sick        3000.0    56.6
1  jenifer      50      Emergency   2500.6    51.6
2  Tom          10      sick        Nan       46.2
3  Sam          5       Casual      Nan       47.2
4  Mady         6       sick        unknown   Nan
```

I want to delete records where there is datatype error in numerical columns(Leaves,Salary,Performance).
If numerical columns contains strings then that row show be deleted from data frame?

```
df[['Leaves','Salary','Performance']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = 'coerce')
```

but this will covert values to Nan.

Comment: once you got Nan, then simply drop the Nan's.

Comment: but my data frame already has Nan, it will also remove my actual Nan

Comment: then before doing transformation using "apply", do fillna() and have some unique value, then do the transformation, drop all Nan, and then convert unique values back to Nan.

Comment: we can do that, but i don't think it is the most optimize way to do it. thanks

Comment: @Mohekar Do not abuse the tags, your question is not about a specific version of python so the tags that indicate it are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from a note concerning your sample data:

It contains *Nan* strings, which are **not** among strings automatically
recognized as *NaN*s.
To treat them as *NaN*, I read the source text with *read_fwf*,
passing *na_values=['Nan']*.

And now get down to the main task:

Define a function to check whether a cell is acceptable:

```
def isAcceptable(cell):
    if pd.isna(cell) or cell == 'unknown':
        return True
    return all(c.isdigit() or c == '.' for c in cell)
```

I noticed that you accept *NaN* values.
You also a cell if it contains **only** *unknown* string, but you don't
accept a cell if such word is **enclosed** between e.g. quotes.

If you change your mind about what is / is not acceptable, change the
above function accordingly.

Then, to leave only rows with all acceptable values in all 3 mentioned
columns, run:

```
df[df[['Leaves', 'Salary', 'Performance']].applymap(isAcceptable).all(axis=1)]
```